# why is include in my PHP file not including my variables?

Tags: php, android, php-include

I have 3 php files in my Android app - `dbConnect.php`, which connects with the database, `volleyLogin.php`, which logs in the user, and `UserDetails.php`, which gets some info about the logged in user.

They work perfectly when running the files in my browser but when run from my Android App `UserDetails.php` isn't working. It keeps returning '0 results' and I am told the variable `username` is undefined even though I use the `include` statement which is supposed to insert the content of one PHP file into another PHP file.

My `dbConnect.php` looks like this :

```
<?php

define ('HOST', 'localhost');
define ('USER', 'root');
define ('PASS', 'password');
define ('DB', 'dbname');

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "dbname") or die('Unable to Connect');

?>
```

My `volleyLogin.php` is like this :

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$username = $_POST['username'];

include('dbConnect.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(isset($check)){

        echo 'success';
} else {
        echo 'Could not log in';
}
}

?>
```

And `UserDetails.php` looks like this :

```
<?php
include('dbConnect.php');
include('volleyLogin.php');

$resultSet = $con->query("SELECT category.cat_name FROM category INNER JOIN user ON category.user_id =
user.user_id WHERE user.username = '$username' ")

or die($con->error);

if ($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {

        while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {

$catname = $rows['cat_name'];

        echo "<p> Name: $catname </p>";
}}
        else {
   echo "0 results";
}
//echo "userdetails.php works";

$con->close();

?>
```

The problem line is :

```
$resultSet = $con->query("SELECT category.cat_name FROM category INNER JOIN user ON category.user_id =
user.user_id WHERE user.username = '$username' ")
```

Comment: Use `require` instead of `include` and check the log.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong: `mysqli_*()` functions basically either return an object/result handle, or a boolean true (success)/false (failure). They ALWAYS return something, so having:

```
$check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(isset($check)){
```

is wrong. `$check` will ALWAYS be set. You need to explicitly check for boolean false to detect failure:

```
if ($check === false) { 
   die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

And note that in none of your sample code do you define `$username`, so your query is doing `WHERE user.username = ''`, and probably matching `0` rows

Comment: I'll look into your answer but is `$username` not defined in `volleyLogin.php` when I say `$username = $_POST['username'];` ?